# Submit Button Not Responding Onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

Form submit button wont respond to click. Developer console and network wont show anything while clicking the button. The issue occurs only to the Customers those who are coming to the site by clicking on Adword from Google Search result.

**Here is the button code:**

```
<button type="button" value="proceed" title="Submit Quote Request" class="button btn-proceed-checkout btn-checkout" onclick="r4qForm.submit(this);">Send</button>
```

I have posted the entire form code at: http://pastebin.com/kncWqe5w

Comment: Change `r4qForm.submit = function(button) {` to `r4qForm.mysubmit = function(button) {` and call mysubmit instead

Answer (score 1):

1. Set button type to "submit"
2. remove `onclick="r4qForm.submit(this);"`
3. assign `r4qForm.submit` function

Comment: Then he cannot pass the button name/ID - he will need to add event target checking

Comment: @artemsky Validation did not happen and blank form also got submitted. Am I missing something here?